# How to make a Timer accurate? (Flash / ActionScript 3.0)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, timer

I'm using the following method to dispatch a sound in X times/minute (X is determined through bpm, which is a NumericStepper object)

```
var mainTimer:Timer = new Timer(60 / (bpm.value * 1000),0);
mainTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fl_TimerHandler,false, 0, true); 
mainTimer.start();

function fl_TimerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
     {
        metroTransform.volume = vol;
        flash.media.SoundMixer.soundTransform = metroTransform;
        metroChannel = metro.play();
        mainTimer.delay = 60 / bpm.value * 1000;
      }
```

According to this http://www.metronomeonline.com/ the sound is not sitting well. Is there something I can do to fix this problem I'm stuck in?

Path to the output file I'm getting: http://conatur.net/metroBig.swf

Comment: did you try to disable the volume transform? each time you call the function you are calling flash.media.SoundMixer you should create an object and instantiate that outside of the function just like metroTransform is. Just a guess here but if you are using a very low frame rate maybe try bumping it up.

Comment: You have a number of problems here.  The first and most deadly is that Flash has an incurable sound latency problem, so even if your code were perfected you would still never be able to assure that the sound plays exactly on cue.  @Valkie has half of your answer but the other half is simply a symptom of the fact that you'll never truly "cure" the latency issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Accurate_timer-17332.html might help you.

> **Problem**
>   The delay between 2 events of the timer class depends on many factors ( fps, memory, played movie clip end i.e. ). The timeout set to property delay of timer class is only approximate so there needs to be a way to increase the accuracy of the timer.
>
> **Solution**
>   My solution to increase the accuracy is to extend the timer class and force the timer to make more cycles depending of the custom property accurate. In this way the delay between 2 events of the timer will be set delay - + accurate /2. Because the rising of the event depends form many factors truly delay between 2 events is from: delay - accurate/2 to next fired event from flash player.

Answer (score 0):

Hum shouldn't the delay value be

```
60000 / bpm.value
// with BPM = 80 we have 60000/80 = 750
```

instead of

```
60 / (bpm.value * 1000)
// with BPM = 80 we have 60/80000 = 0.00075
```

And as the Time delay values is described in the documentation:

> delay:Number — The delay between timer
>   events, in milliseconds. A delay lower
>   than 20 milliseconds is not
>   recommended. Timer frequency is
>   limited to 60 frames per second,
>   meaning a delay lower than 16.6
>   milliseconds causes runtime problems.

I guess 750 milliseconds would fit be better than 0.00075 milliseconds.

Though, when I test your SWF and set the BPM at 60, it sounds every second without problem so *I guess the bpm.value is not what it looks like*.

---

Anyhow, when I open your swf and the "metronomeonline" website on two tabs (or windows) and set them at the same BPM, they sound synchronized to me.

Comment: Did you keep listening for some time? Also, the problem gets worst when the bpm is higher than 130

Comment: 130 BTM is approximately 460 ms, so it's far upper from the 20 ms limit and it should not be a problem. However, the timers in AS3 as in almost all languages are based on the main loop and time to time the loop takes longer than others (for technical reasons)... That's why it's difficult to have a very high precision timer, and that's particularly true with languages that wrap on top of others as AS3 do. I think that the time event is OK.

Comment: And the best way to verify if your timer event is OK, is to not reset your display counter at 5, then to set a given BTM (say 180) for a relatively "long" time (say 5 minutes, so it's easy to count with your watch), and finally to divide the counter value obtained by the total time (in min). Thus you will know if it was fired the good number of time or not (5 min with 180 BPM should give 900). The more your result is close to the expected result the more your timer event was precise... and if it is precise enough that mean that the problem come from the sound not being played all the time.

Comment: How long (in milliseconds) is the sound you play at each tic ? Maybe your sound is not always yet finished and reset when you call your next `metro.play();` (I do not remember exactly how sound works in AS3 and I don't have anything to test by now).