# How to create actionscript Timer that doesn't finish earlier

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I'm developing a game where there are 'processes' created and they create their own timer. Once the timer is finished, a request 'process finished' is dispatched to the server.
Sometimes the problem is that the timer finishes earlier and because in my test environment the client and the server are on the same machine, everything happens very fast and the server fails its check if the process has expired.

This is because the actionscript's Timer dispatched timer complete a little bit earlier. Now, I saw a lot of articles regarding the problem, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955044/how-to-make-a-timer-accurate-flash-actionscript-3-0), but none of these seem to answer my question. I don't want to create a timer that is accurate, but to create a timer that never dispatches earlier, no matter if the client has ran at slightly higher FPS rates while it's been running.
How do I achieve that? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to use time based Timer?

Comment: @SzRaPnEL What is this? If you're mentioning flash.util.Timer, that's what I'm using

Answer (score 0):

Use Date.getTime() when creating the timer and when the timer is done. Subtract the second value from the first. This gives you the amount of time that has passed (in milliseconds). If the value is less than it should be, don't dispatch the event.